# Where to start when worldbuilding cultures?

Tags: culture

I just started to work on a low tech, non magical world. How should I go about create cultures without just making them a real world culture but with a slight adjustment?

Comment: How or Where to start creating something is not something that has a fixed formula. For many it will depend on personal preferences and you can see examples of this throughout history (basically every culture has a history book tied to it). This answer is far too broad to have a correct answer, because everyone world-builds differently. Copying and changing is often the first step in learning how to create your own things.

Answer (score 0):

All well-established cultures are descended from great works.

A great work usually has a well-considered guiding principle.

Over time these principles compete against each other in the culture till these works (and their contained principles) are organized into a hierarchy of values. That hierarchy then guides the decisions of that culture.

Western Cultures have works such as the Illiad, Christian/Judaeo Bibles, the Elements, etc... and each culture has organized these into different hierarchies, sometimes dropping a work, adding another, or swapping their relative importance.

Eastern cultures do not have those same works informing them. I'm no expert on eastern culture, but I am aware that the works by Confucious and Sun Tzu are in there, somewhere, informing those cultures' principles and participating in how they value, and hence what they choose.

This also serves to point out which cultures will easily communicate (by sharing identical/similar works containing similar principles at various levels of formalization) or how difficult it is to communicate (by how differently organized, or dissimilar the works are).

---

So I would start by picking a principle. Have it written by someone, who lived some when, who was something, and how it came to be considered important. Probably some king, bishop, popular uprising, etc... Now you have a cornerstone.

Keep adding principles and have them come into conflict with each other. If they cause a schism congrats you have two similar but different nascent cultures. have them rearrange those principles, drop some and add others.

Also, keep an eye on geography. Principles that get you killed, don't stay around for long. Also groups that are relatively isolated have difficulty maintaining the communication needed to keep principles aligned. This will lead to drift.

Comment: The works which support the base of "western" culture are Homer's *Illiad* and *Odyssey*, the Xenophon's *Anabasis*, Vergil's *Aeneid* and so on. The Bible is very important in "western" culture, of course, but it is a late addition and the fundamentals of the culture were already set when it was received; consider the differences between the very Oriental Hebrew parts of the Bible and the very much Hellenistic specifically Christian parts.

Comment: I agree with most of your point. The only disagreement is with "the fundamentals of the culture were already set". It presumes that a culture cannot change its core beliefs when informed by new ideas. I grant you that this can be a very slow process taking many hundreds of years. I think I caused a misunderstanding when discussing the corner stone of eastern culture. I can see how it can be infered that I meant that the various "bibles" should be categorised as a corner stone of western culture. That is not what I meant. I'll correct that.

Answer (score 0):

What your asking for is similar to alternate history, first I think you should choose what culture you want to draw reference form then learn as much of there culture as you can as to not misinterpret anything and then switch something about them and figure out what else changes.

but if that dosen't work or just isnt your thing, googling a culture wheel. They are basically step by step culture builders.